# Repeated Splitting of an Edge into Pairs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If one starts with a single edge, splits off another two edges at one vertex in the next step, splits off two edges from each of the two new vertices at the following step and so on, what would be the growth rate of the number of edges with the number of steps?

The number of branches for first few steps are $1$, $3$, $7$, $15$, $31$, and so on.

Comment: it is $2^s-1$ where $s$ is step number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each step, there are twice as many vertices as in the previous step (since half of the vertices are new and two new vertices are formed for all vertices that were new). Since there are $2$ vertices in the first step, there are $2^s$ vertices in step $s$. Since the constructed graph is a tree, it has one edge fewer than vertices, so the number of edges in step $s$ is $2^s-1$.